# Can't Install Aps Outside Ubuntu Software Because Nothing Happens

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

Im trying to install sublime text on ubuntu but it doesnt work because when i hit install nothing happens

[image: as you can see here]

pls help :/ :(

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are we talking here?

Comment: The version is 17.04

Comment: Please kindly accept the answer, :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens at times, lets use `PPA` options to install them.

#### Sublime Text 2

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

#### Sublime Text 3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Comment: Ok i was able to do it this way but does that mean that i have to things like this (use the terminal) for every app/program i want to get/install?

Comment: Just bear with Ubuntu 17.01 as they get bugs fixed, I also experienced the same thing when I first installed Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Gdebi package manager
**install gdebi by**

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Now you can install any **".deb"** file by right click on them and open with gdebi
you can download latest sublime **.deb** from the link
https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb